# How to input text to program running in terminal immediately

Tags: terminal

I wrote a very simple bash script to try to input the word "password" into a program running in terminal.

```
./program
echo "password"
```

But when I run this script, "password" is printed after the program finishes running. How can I use the script to input "password" into the program immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for piping

```
echo "password" | ./program
```